# Batch Command Line Arguments

Tags: batch-file, scripting, args

Is it possible to pipe in a .txt file as a command line argument to a batch file?

For example, I am looking to call

```
./program components.txt
```

Then use every line of components.txt as arguments to a function I call inside my batch file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If args.txt contains a list of command-line arguments to your executable (one per line), you could use something like this:

```
    @echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    set ARGS=
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type args.txt') do (
      set ARGS=!ARGS! %%a
    )
    .\program %ARGS%
    endlocal
```

Comment: Does it matter if ./program is not an executable? What if it is a local command?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether _program_ is an internal cmd.exe command or an executable. However if it is a shell script (batch file), use `call` to run it (e.g., `call .\scriptname %ARGS%`).

Comment: Sorry let me specify... I'm calling "p4 sync %ARGS%" on that line... NO executable is being used from an internal scope.

Comment: The `for` command reads the file args.txt and constructs the ARGS environment variable as a single space-delimited string containing the lines from the file (i.e., spaces between instead of newlines). What you do with that string is up to you.